# cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Root'

Tags: xml, validation, xsd-validation

**XSD Sample**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="shiporder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" />  
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**XML response Sample**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shiporder orderid="str1234">
  <orderperson>str1234</orderperson>
  <name>str1234</name>
  <address>str1234</address>
</shiporder>
```

**Schema Validate Dom Source**

http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3307

**Schema Validate StreamSource**

http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3306

Validating as Stream source works fine. When validating with DomSource I am experience the error. cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'shiporder'.

What is the reason for this behavior.?

```
My main question why validator.validate(new DOMSource(node));  does not work in shema validation. What is the reason ?
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to post enough info so that others can attempt to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I updated ticket with complete java classes. DomSource , Stream source , XSD and XML response. Thanks for the help

Comment: dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); did not help me out

Answer (score 1):

During the creation of DOM structure you need to explicitly specify that your DOM elements does not belong to any namespace. You can do this by calling `org.w3c.dom.Document#createElementNS` instead of `org.w3c.dom.Document#createElement`, where `namespaceURI` has `null` value.

Example: `document.createElementNS(null, qualifiedName)`.